# Referring a series of figures

Tags: floats, cross-referencing

When I run the add file, I get:

> Chapter 1 chap
>
> 1.1 sec
>
> figures 1.1 - 1.1. Just a figure 1.1 Just b figure 1.1

Clearly this is wrong but does it happen?

```
\documentclass{report}

%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\chapter{chap}
\section{sec}
figures \ref{a} - \ref{c}.

Just a figure \ref{a}
Just b figure \ref{b}

\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{mem0per.png}
  \caption{A figure}
  \label{a}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{mem0per.png}
  \caption{B figure}
  \label{b}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{mem0per.png}
  \caption{C figure}
  \label{c}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This input does not produce the output you describe for me; the labels' values are as expected.

Comment: The output you show cannot be generated by the code; it would be if all `\label` commands precede the `\caption`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran you example as is and the results appear to be correct:

[image]

**Update:** Indeed, as @egreg commented, if you have the `\label` before each `\caption`, you get the results that you are seeing:

[image]

Comment: Yes. What happened is the following: I placed the ``\label``'s before the ``\captions``'s got the wrong out put, rerun pdflatex *once* got the same result and post it here. Thanks